# What kind of kivy widgets can I use to implement an android phone app like UI?

Tags: kivy

I'm learning to write my first kivy app. I would like to implement the UI a kind of the android phone call app, that is it have several buttons under the bottom of the screen, and when press a button, the above screen would change to the corresponding contents (maybe a list of records, or a classical settings screen).

I think I may need two customized container widgets for the button groups and the above content, and the content widget may need to dynamically remove all child widgets and add corresponding new child widgets for the button on_press event. I'm not sure whether the idea here is appropriate,  or there is a ready solution for this type of classical android app ui using kivy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are asking for the [ScreenManager](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html). Kivy provides a nice example but here is another example. I think it is more similar to what you are looking for:

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

```
Builder.load_string("""
<Phone>:
    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: 'center'
        anchor_y: 'top'
        ScreenManager:
            size_hint: 1, .9
            id: _screen_manager
            Screen:
                name: 'screen1'
                Label: 
                    text: 'The first screen'
            Screen:
                name: 'screen2'
                Label: 
                    text: 'The second screen'
    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: 'center'
        anchor_y: 'bottom'
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            size_hint: 1, .1
            Button:
                text: 'Go to Screen 1'
                on_press: _screen_manager.current = 'screen1'
            Button:
                text: 'Go to Screen 2'
                on_press: _screen_manager.current = 'screen2'""")

class Phone(FloatLayout):
    pass

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Phone()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Comment: Thanks toto_tico, that's very similar to what I wanted, however I'd like to keep the buttons unchanged while changing the above content screens by on_press. Anyway I think ScreenManager should be the choice, thanks again.

Comment: Sure. The `ScreenManager` is a `Widget` itself and can go wherever you want it. I modified the code so now you got what you wanted. I didn't understand the question the first time very well, sorry. If you think this now answers your question please mark it at so. [StackOverflow About](http://stackoverflow.com/about)